# Assigning Max Value After np.genfromtxt

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to find out what time (column 2) the highest price (column 5) happened every day (column 1), then plot those times visually.

I believe the first step is to look at the date, then find the max of column 5. Would this be done with a for loop? What happens if there are 2 of the same?

Next I'd like to visually see the time (histograph) that the highest price happened with loading many more days in the file.

When I try to find the max I get an error.

The data sucessfully loads with this code:

```
import numpy as np

my_data = np.genfromtxt('downloads/USDJPY.csv', delimiter=",", dtype=None, names=True, encoding='utf-8')

print (my_data)
```

---

This is the output... I need to find the max (column 5), this is just one day of data..

```
[('6/3/19', '7:05', 'USD/JPY', 108.37 , 108.37 , 108.345, 108.345)
 ('6/3/19', '7:10', 'USD/JPY', 108.345, 108.345, 108.325, 108.325)
 ('6/3/19', '7:15', 'USD/JPY', 108.33 , 108.36 , 108.33 , 108.34 )
 ('6/3/19', '7:20', 'USD/JPY', 108.335, 108.335, 108.295, 108.305)
 ('6/3/19', '7:25', 'USD/JPY', 108.305, 108.305, 108.27 , 108.305)
 ('6/3/19', '7:30', 'USD/JPY', 108.3  , 108.3  , 108.25 , 108.26 )
 ('6/3/19', '7:35', 'USD/JPY', 108.265, 108.295, 108.265, 108.29 )
 ('6/3/19', '7:40', 'USD/JPY', 108.275, 108.29 , 108.25 , 108.29 )
 ('6/3/19', '7:45', 'USD/JPY', 108.285, 108.29 , 108.275, 108.29 )
 ('6/3/19', '7:50', 'USD/JPY', 108.295, 108.35 , 108.295, 108.35 )
 ('6/3/19', '7:55', 'USD/JPY', 108.355, 108.355, 108.325, 108.33 )
 ('6/3/19', '8:00', 'USD/JPY', 108.335, 108.36 , 108.325, 108.35 )
 ('6/3/19', '8:05', 'USD/JPY', 108.345, 108.375, 108.32 , 108.37 )
 ('6/3/19', '8:10', 'USD/JPY', 108.375, 108.38 , 108.365, 108.365)
 ('6/3/19', '8:15', 'USD/JPY', 108.365, 108.37 , 108.33 , 108.33 )
 ('6/3/19', '8:20', 'USD/JPY', 108.335, 108.345, 108.33 , 108.345)
 ('6/3/19', '8:25', 'USD/JPY', 108.35 , 108.38 , 108.35 , 108.38 )
 ('6/3/19', '8:30', 'USD/JPY', 108.37 , 108.39 , 108.37 , 108.38 )
 ('6/3/19', '8:35', 'USD/JPY', 108.375, 108.435, 108.37 , 108.42 )
 ('6/3/19', '8:40', 'USD/JPY', 108.42 , 108.425, 108.4  , 108.405)
 ('6/3/19', '8:45', 'USD/JPY', 108.41 , 108.415, 108.35 , 108.355)
 ('6/3/19', '8:50', 'USD/JPY', 108.355, 108.36 , 108.3  , 108.325)
 ('6/3/19', '8:55', 'USD/JPY', 108.32 , 108.33 , 108.265, 108.27 )
 ('6/3/19', '9:00', 'USD/JPY', 108.27 , 108.29 , 108.25 , 108.265)
 ('6/3/19', '9:05', 'USD/JPY', 108.22 , 108.34 , 108.195, 108.27 )
 ('6/3/19', '9:10', 'USD/JPY', 108.27 , 108.365, 108.25 , 108.34 )
 ('6/3/19', '9:15', 'USD/JPY', 108.33 , 108.355, 108.3  , 108.32 )
 ('6/3/19', '9:20', 'USD/JPY', 108.31 , 108.33 , 108.29 , 108.33 )
 ('6/3/19', '9:25', 'USD/JPY', 108.325, 108.33 , 108.315, 108.325)
 ('6/3/19', '9:30', 'USD/JPY', 108.335, 108.345, 108.32 , 108.345)
 ('6/3/19', '9:35', 'USD/JPY', 108.345, 108.345, 108.325, 108.33 )
 ('6/3/19', '9:40', 'USD/JPY', 108.34 , 108.37 , 108.33 , 108.355)
 ('6/3/19', '9:45', 'USD/JPY', 108.355, 108.4  , 108.345, 108.395)
 ('6/3/19', '9:50', 'USD/JPY', 108.39 , 108.41 , 108.38 , 108.385)
 ('6/3/19', '9:55', 'USD/JPY', 108.385, 108.385, 108.35 , 108.35 )
 ('6/3/19', '10:00', 'USD/JPY', 108.355, 108.39 , 108.355, 108.375)
 ('6/3/19', '10:05', 'USD/JPY', 108.37 , 108.41 , 108.36 , 108.405)
 ('6/3/19', '10:10', 'USD/JPY', 108.4  , 108.405, 108.37 , 108.37 )
 ('6/3/19', '10:15', 'USD/JPY', 108.375, 108.375, 108.35 , 108.36 )
 ('6/3/19', '10:20', 'USD/JPY', 108.36 , 108.37 , 108.355, 108.37 )
 ('6/3/19', '10:25', 'USD/JPY', 108.37 , 108.425, 108.37 , 108.41 )
 ('6/3/19', '10:30', 'USD/JPY', 108.405, 108.42 , 108.395, 108.405)
 ('6/3/19', '10:35', 'USD/JPY', 108.405, 108.435, 108.405, 108.415)
 ('6/3/19', '10:40', 'USD/JPY', 108.405, 108.405, 108.38 , 108.405)
 ('6/3/19', '10:45', 'USD/JPY', 108.4  , 108.425, 108.395, 108.415)
 ('6/3/19', '10:50', 'USD/JPY', 108.42 , 108.445, 108.4  , 108.41 )
 ('6/3/19', '10:55', 'USD/JPY', 108.4  , 108.415, 108.4  , 108.405)
 ('6/3/19', '11:00', 'USD/JPY', 108.395, 108.395, 108.38 , 108.39 )
 ('6/3/19', '11:05', 'USD/JPY', 108.39 , 108.41 , 108.39 , 108.39 )]
```

I've tried this to find the max and get an error.

```
import numpy as np

my_data = np.genfromtxt('downloads/USDJPY.csv', delimiter=",", dtype=None, names=True, encoding='utf-8')

High = my_data.max[:4]

print (High)
```

I expect the output to be High = 108.435 and that happened at 8:35.

Once I find the high, how can I pass that to the time bin?

I will also be doing the low.

Comment: You have a `structured array` - it is 1d with multiple fields (instead of columns).  What's the `dtype`?  You have to reference fields by name.  Indexing with `[:4]` means pick the first 4 rows.

Comment: You might find a Dataframe easier to understand.  Try `pandas.read_csv`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about the Dataframe. I was only looking at numpy since eventually I'd like to create a histograph of all the times a max happened.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you could solve this by looking at your np array and finding the row # of the highest value in col 5, then get the value in col 1 of the correspondin row

```
loc_max = my_data[:,4].argmax() #gives row of the max in col 5
time_max = my_data[loc_max,0]
```

but it looks like you might've had issues importing due to the delimiter..this solution will work if you are able to properly import your data into a np array as described in the question

Comment: Thank you I will try this also.

Answer (score 0):

I can recreate a portion of your array with:

```
In [210]: data = np.array([('6/3/19', '7:05', 'USD/JPY', 108.37 , 108.37 , 108.345, 108.345), 
     ...:  ('6/3/19', '7:10', 'USD/JPY', 108.345, 108.345, 108.325, 108.325), 
     ...:  ('6/3/19', '7:15', 'USD/JPY', 108.33 , 108.36 , 108.33 , 108.34 ), 
     ...:  ('6/3/19', '7:20', 'USD/JPY', 108.335, 108.335, 108.295, 108.305), 
     ...:  ('6/3/19', '7:25', 'USD/JPY', 108.305, 108.305, 108.27 , 108.305), 
     ...:  ('6/3/19', '7:30', 'USD/JPY', 108.3  , 108.3  , 108.25 , 108.26 )], 
     ...: dtype='U7,U4,U10,f,f,f,f') 
     ...:  
     ...:  
     ...:                                                                                            
In [211]: data                                                                                       
Out[211]: 
array([('6/3/19', '7:05', 'USD/JPY', 108.37 , 108.37 , 108.345, 108.345),
       ('6/3/19', '7:10', 'USD/JPY', 108.345, 108.345, 108.325, 108.325),
       ('6/3/19', '7:15', 'USD/JPY', 108.33 , 108.36 , 108.33 , 108.34 ),
       ('6/3/19', '7:20', 'USD/JPY', 108.335, 108.335, 108.295, 108.305),
       ('6/3/19', '7:25', 'USD/JPY', 108.305, 108.305, 108.27 , 108.305),
       ('6/3/19', '7:30', 'USD/JPY', 108.3  , 108.3  , 108.25 , 108.26 )],
      dtype=[('f0', '<U7'), ('f1', '<U4'), ('f2', '<U10'), ('f3', '<f4'), ('f4', '<f4'), ('f5', '<f4'), ('f6', '<f4')])
```

This has a compound dtype - with 7 fields

```
In [212]: data.dtype                                                                                 
Out[212]: dtype([('f0', '<U7'), ('f1', '<U4'), ('f2', '<U10'), ('f3', '<f4'), ('f4', '<f4'), ('f5', '<f4'), ('f6', '<f4')])
```

fields are accessed by name.  Number accesses rows, records:

```
In [213]: data['f4']                                                                                 
Out[213]: 
array([108.37 , 108.345, 108.36 , 108.335, 108.305, 108.3  ],
      dtype=float32)
```

The max and its position is:

```
In [214]: np.argmax(data['f4'])                                                                      
Out[214]: 0
In [215]: np.max(data['f4'])                                                                         
Out[215]: 108.37
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this. I've thought about bailing on the ng.gentxt to get the data and manually pasting it into the code. My worry is the array could eventually be very large. Thanks for your help, I'm obviously very new at this and this is my first real project.